# Can BDT do squares?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, physics, decision-tree, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to separate background from signal where it is known that the quantity `x^2 - y^2` is the physical reason why the background and signal are different. If I provide x and y as input variables, the BDT is having the hard time figuring out how to achieve the separation. Is BDT unable to do squares?

Answer (score 0):

No, a binary decision tree is unable to take squares of input features. Given input features x, y, it will try to approximate the desired function by subdividing the x,y plane along vertical and horizontal lines. Let us take a look at an example: I fit a decision tree classifier to a square grid of points, and plot the decision boundary.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(-5.5, 5.5, 1)
y = np.arange(-5.0, 6.0, 1)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
#the function we want to learn:
target = xx.ravel()**2 - yy.ravel()**2 > 0
data = np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]
#Fit a decision tree:
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(data, target)

#Plot the decision boundary:
xxplot, yyplot = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-7, 7, 0.1),
                     np.arange(-7, 7, 0.1))

Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xxplot.ravel(), yyplot.ravel()]) 

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xxplot.shape)
plt.contourf(xxplot, yyplot, Z, cmap=plt.cm.hot)

# Plot also the training points
plt.scatter(xx.ravel(), yy.ravel(), c=target, cmap=plt.cm.flag)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.title("Decision boundary for a binary decision tree learning a function x**2 - y**2 > 0")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here you can see what kind of boundaries a decision tree can learn: piecewise-rectangular. They are not going to approximate your function well, especially in the area where there are few training points. Since you know that x^2 - y^2 is the quantity that determines the answer, you can just add it as a new feature instead of trying to learn it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand. In principle, if I design a fairly complex BDT, it should still only be able to come up with an approximation that may resemble a square but that might be impractical. I also understand that if I know the quantity x^2 - y^2 I can just provide it as the input variable. But just as an academic exercise, if I did not know that x^2 - y^2 is the quantity, what kind of ML algorithm is more suited to solve such a problem? Please do share your experience. Thanks.